# Issue with JavaScript getter in iOS 5

Tags: javascript, ios5

I'm using JavaScript getters in a web site which is optimized to run on iPad. Everything was running fine but after updating to iOS 5, the site stopped working.

Eventually I have found what was the issue.

I have a configuration object which contains read-only properties (that's why I used getters) with the following structure:

```
var Config = (function() {

    var DateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy";

    return {
       get DateFormat() { return DateFormat; }
    };

}());
```

For some reason, the JavaScript engine in iOS 5 doesn't like that the name of the getter (DateFormat) is the same as the private variable's name. If I rename that to _DateFormat, it works:

```
var Config = (function() {

    var _DateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy";

    return {
       get DateFormat() { return _DateFormat; }
    };

}());
```

My question is: Is this how it supposed to work, or is it a bug in the JavaScript engine ?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that if you are using JQuery or another JS library you are calling the dateFormat function somehow.

Here is an example where there's a function for JQuery called dateFormat:

http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format

Comment: I don't think that this is relevant, because my DateFormat getter has nothing to do with jQuery or other JS libraries. Even if there was a function called 'dateFormat' included by a library or in another JS file, my getter is namespaced (Config.DateFormat) so there is no chance that there is a naming issue here.